# jquery masonry image size

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-masonry

This is what I currently have, however, the image is compressed to fit the size of the text's width.  No matter what size I specify in the html, it doesn't change.  Any light on this matter?

```
$('#append').click(function(){
    var $boxes = $('<div class="box">'+balls($iterator)+'</div>');
    $container.append( $boxes ).masonry( 'appended', $boxes );

});


function balls($i){
    $iterator += 1;
    return '<p>'+$test[$iterator][1][2]+'</p><p><img src="'+$test[$iterator][2]+'" alt="'+$test[$iterator][1][2]+'" height="196" width="319"></a></p>';
}
```

[image]

Comment: I dont see a open anchor tag in `balls($i)` return statement but there is a close tag `</a>`. Is it a typo ?

Comment: Oh yeah, it is.  That wouldn't affect it though huh?

Comment: I updated my OP to reflect what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Should this be triggered with imagesLoaded plugin ? From [masonry site](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html)

`"If your content contains any images, you’ll want to ensure that Masonry is triggered after all the images your content has loaded"`

Try

```
$container.append( $boxes ).imagesLoaded( function(){$container.masonry( 'appended', $boxes);});
```

Comment: I didn't post all my code, I had this above that: 

    var $container = $('#container');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
   itemSelector: '.box',
   columnWidth: 100,
   isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
  });
 });
Which, I think does the same thing.

Comment: And I just tried amending my line to the way you have that one, no change.  

Is this something simple with HTML?  Or is this a limitation of Masonry?

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/LnL4L/) . I tried to simulate your environment.Is this what you try to do?